# compiling multiple files with -D option using gcc

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a project with multiple .cpp and .h files. I have a file called Globals.h which is included in all .cpp files. 
Now when compiling this file I use some -D options. These options affect all files not just Globals.h.

In my makefile I had to use the same -D options when compiling every file. Of course when removing those options some "undefined" errors arise.

This means every time I change one of these options I have to recompile the whole project.
Is there a way that would let me compile ONLY Globals.h with these options?

This is a part from my makefile:
lines that create Globals.o :

```
Globals.o : $(GlobalsLib) $(GlobalsInc)
       g++ -c -Wall $(CodeDefined) $(UserDefined) $(GlobalsLib) -std=c++0x -o Globals.o
```

`$(GlobalsLib)` and `$(GlobalsInc)` are paths to files `Globals.h` and `Globals.cpp`
`$(CodeDefined)` and `$(UserDefined)` are -U and -D options this code is for creating another .o file:

```
NT_FFT_Decomp.o : $(GlobalsLib) $(GlobalsInc) $(NT_DecompLib) $(NT_DecompInc)
       g++ -c -Wall $(CodeDefined) $(UserDefined) $(NT_DecompLib) -std=c++0x -o NT_FFT_Decomp.o
```

`(NT_DecompLib) $(NT_DecompInc)` are also paths to files. Notice that I had to add the same options in the g++ command. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: header are not compiled, so you cannot compile only the Global.h. Every time you change a header you should re-compile the entire project to make sure all sources was compile with the same version of the header.

Comment: You should use macros for the compiler (so `CXX = g++` as a macro definition, and then `$(CXX)` in place of `g++` on the command lines), and for its flags (classically something like `CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++0x` as the macro definition, and then use `$(CXXFLAGS)` on the command lines).  This means you can change the flags once (on the command line if necessary) and it changes for the complete invocation of `make`.

Comment: I already did that . I just changed them when i posted this question

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how headers work.

Headers are not separate compilation units.  Perhaps this will make more sense if you precompile all of your files, via the `-E` flag (I think).  This will leave you with a bunch of `.i` (I think) files that will actually be compiled.  Note that the headers are now gone, but their contents are spread across the different source files.  That is what you actually have to recompile each time.

There are ways to minimize source recompilation.  For instance this situation:

foo.h

```
int foo = 1;
```

Can be turned into this one:

foo.h

```
extern int foo;
```

foo.cpp

```
int foo = 1;
```

So you can now change the value of `foo` without recompiling.

But unfortunately, it also sounds like your header is just too big.  If you throw everything in one header you're going to be doing a lot of recompilation.  Factor more specifically and this may be more avoidable.

Also (or alternatively?) use [precompiled headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) to reduce compilation time.  I've never programmed with them but they solve this problem I understand.